# SwiftUI: Variable strings not exported for localization

Tags: swiftui, localization

As per Apple documentation, this should work:

> If you initialize a text view with a string variable rather than a string literal, the view triggers the init(*:) initializer instead, because it assumes that you don’t want localization in that case. If you do want to localize the value stored in a string variable, you can choose to call the init(*:tableName:bundle:comment:) initializer by first creating a LocalizedStringKey instance from the string variable:
>
> Text(LocalizedStringKey(someString)) // Localizes the contents of `someString`.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:tablename:bundle:comment:)

This is also recommended here: https://www.ibabbleon.com/swiftui_localization_tutorial.html

However, at least in my case, it does not. In the following example, only "Some content 1" value is exported for localization.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let text = "Some content 2"
    var body: some View {
        Text("Some content 1", comment: "This text is exported for localization, as expected.")
            .padding()
        Text(LocalizedStringKey(text), comment: "This text is not exported for localization, which is not expected behaviour.")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

In the app settings, "Use compiler to extract swift strings" is set to Yes.

What am I missing?

Comment: It says "If you do want to localize" - it does not say "if you want to export for localization" - 1st is a framework feature, 2nd belongs to Xcode behavior. Works as documented - shown localized string for variable in run-time.

Comment: I see. So following the example, "Some content 2" will not be exported for localization, but it will be localized if the corresponding key will be found? I'm not sure I see the sense in that; I would like the strings to both be exported and localized. After some testing, I see that I can declare `let content2: LocalizedStringKey = "Some content 2"` and use it as `Text(content2)`. This gets exported for localization just fine. But I'm not sure how to add a comment to the string. If I add `Text(content2, comment: "Some comment")`, the comment will not be exported for localization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so after tinkering with localization some more, I found an approach that works well.

The tutorial I linked to (https://www.ibabbleon.com/swiftui_localization_tutorial.html) does not talk about this, and makes things confusing with LocalizedStringKey and Text(String, comment: String). Some other tutorials also go down this route, but it makes code really ugly because it moves data into Text. So if you want to separate data from the view, you have to include Text (a UI element) in the view model. Alternatively, if you use LocalizedStringKey, you can't include comments for the translator.

Fortunately, there is a much simpler way!

```
struct ContentView: View {
  let normalString = "This is not exported for localization. Good for previews!"
  let localizedString = String(localized: "This is exported for localization.", comment: "You can add a comment for the translator, too!")

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(normalString)
      Text(localizedString)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This API is only available on the latest OSes. So it is more reasonable to use the old NSLocalizedString(_, comment:_) macro.

Answer (score 1):

You already found that doing `let content2: LocalizedStringKey = "Some content 2"` fixes your issue but still had a question about how to include a comment.

Apple noted in their [Localize your SwiftUI App](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10220/) session at WWDC 21 that one approach is to have the argument to your view be of the type `Text` so that you can provide the comment.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let text = Text("Some content 2", comment: "This gets exported!")
    var body: some View {
        Text("Some content 1", comment: "This text is exported for localization, as expected.")
            .padding()
        text
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know, but it's not useful for injected Strings. For example, I have `enum ColorScheme: String, Identifiable {` that holds dark/light options, like `case light = "Light"` along with `var id: String { self.rawValue }`. I want to export this String along with a comment, but if I pass it to ContentView, Xcode wants me to convert it to LocalizedStringKey like `Text(LocalizedStringKey(ColorScheme.dark.id), comment: "Comment")`, which does not export, or wrap it in "" like `Text("\(ColorScheme.light.id)", comment: "Comment."), which exports the string as %@.

Comment: True. It sounds like that specific case doesn't work well with the new localization export stuff. In that case I would probably move away from using the raw value of the cases as the string you want to export and instead have a computed property on the enum like `@ViewBuilder var foo: Text { switch self { case .light: Text("Light", comment: "my comment") } }`

Comment: Because the export process is done at compile time and not run time, any attempt to pass a `String` variable into the `LocalizedStringKey` initializer won't export how you want. It has to know the value of the string for the `LocalizedStringKey` at compile time. All the ways I can think of for this to happen involve having a string literal directly associated with the `LocalizedStringKey` type, either by having it in a variable like `let foo: LocalizedStringKey = "yay"` or by passing a string literal in as the value for a `LocalizedStringKey` parameter like `Text("yay")`

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found 2 ways to localize strings with swiftUI, the first one you can find in this [WWDC talk about localizables](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10220/) or in this [article here](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/swiftui-tutorial-localization/). If you only want to avoid polluting the view with string literals, but not necessarily localize ir, you can do it like this:

Create an swift archive and create an enum like the example:

```
enum MyLocalizable: LocalizedStringKey {
 case mytest
}
```

And now, create an Localizable.strings in your project and set your string.

Example:

```
"mytest" = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
```

And lastly you can acess the value on your view on this form:

```
Text(MyLocalizable.mytest.rawValue)
```